# Relation between two fact tables and filter by datetime

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

We have two Fact tables as below

Fact1

| DeviceKey | DateKey | TimeKey | CustomersIn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230225 | 235612 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230226 | 94123 | 1 |
| 1 | 20230227 | 183408 | 3 |
| 1 | 20230228 | 175926 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230301 | 112319 | 1 |
| 2 | 20230225 | 224623 | 3 |
| 2 | 20230226 | 163452 | 2 |
| 3 | 20230225 | 45603 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230227 | 223451 | 2 |

Fact2

| DeviceKey | EventDatekey | EventTimeKey | ErrorKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230225 | 81625 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230227 | 135409 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230301 | 124143 | 12 |
| 2 | 20230225 | 192324 | 2 |
| 2 | 20230226 | 180732 | 2 |
| 2 | 20230228 | 143919 | 12 |
| 2 | 20230301 | 71452 | 2 |
| 3 | 20230227 | 213451 | 2 |
| 3 | 20230228 | 212451 | 2 |

Display the EventDateKey and EventTimeKey of Fact 2 table, which is greater than the maximum Datekey and TimeKey for each device in Fact 1 table. If two days or 48 hours have passed from the maximum DateKey and TimeKey for each device in Fact 1 table.
Right now, date and time: 2023/03/01 11:58

Result

| DeviceKey | EventDatekey | EventTimeKey | ErrorKey | maxdatetimeKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20230226 | 180732 | 2 | 20230226163452 |
| 2 | 20230228 | 143919 | 12 | 20230226163452 |
| 2 | 20230301 | 71452 | 2 | 20230226163452 |
| 3 | 20230228 | 212451 | 2 | 20230227223451 |

I used this script with the help of @SalVazi,
But this script does not show the maxdatetime column

```
SELECT f2.*
FROM FactDeviceError f2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DeviceKey, MAX(CONCAT(DateKey, FORMAT(TimeKey, '0#####'))) as maxdatetimeKey
  FROM FactTelemetry f1
  GROUP BY DeviceKey
) s ON s.DeviceKey = f2.DeviceKey AND CONCAT(EventDateKey, FORMAT(EventTimeKey, '0#####')) > maxdatetimeKey;
GO
```

How do I reach this conclusion? By creating a view in the database or in SSAS Tabular?

Comment: I don't see the problem here, if you want to show `maxdatetimeKey` you can add it the `SELECT`, ie: `f2.*, s.maxdatetimeKey`

Comment: Yes, your script is correct
I have another problem that the number of my data is large and it takes a lot of time to execute this script, what should I do to solve it?